# Как сделать анимацию обьекта при наведении на него курсором?

Tags: jquery

Плавный переход из одного цвета в другой.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут хороший пример: [Javascript fading - плавное изменение цветов](http://www.tigir.com/fade.htm) или много других по запросу fade javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    $('#element2').fadeTo(400, 0.5);
  });
```

Второму элементу будет присвоено значение прозрачности 0,5 за 400 миллисекунд

А если имеется ввиду плавное изменение цвета на другой, то можно использовать эффект jquery-ui http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен плагин анимации цвета. Взять его можно [оттуда](http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/) или [отсюда](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).